# Integrating $\int _{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z^2-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int _{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z^2-1}$$

$\gamma:$ $it$ and $-1\leq t\leq 1$

The point $-1$ and $1$ are not on $\gamma$, can we say that the integral  is $0$?

Comment: No, $\gamma$ is not a closed curve. You may directly compute it.

Comment: Perhaps the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus would be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can say that it is zero if $\gamma$ is a **closed** curve such that $-1$ and $1$ are not on $\gamma$ and **inside** the domain encircled by $\gamma$.  But here $\gamma$ is not a closed curve., it is a segment.

On the other hand, we can evaluate the integral directly: after letting $z=it$, we get
$$\int _{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z^2-1}=\int _{-1}^1\frac{idt}{(it)^2-1}.$$
Can you take it from here?